# Reversing a string recursion error python

Tags: python

When I return the .join method to reverse the string I call the function itself to do so. How can still reverse this string without using Built-in python methods such as the reversed method.

```
def reverse_string_3(string):

    length = len(string)
    spaces = [' ']
    words = []
    index_tracker = 0

    while index_tracker < length:
        if string[index_tracker] not in spaces:
            beginning_of_word = index_tracker

            # we only want to increment when the index tracker is a letter and not spaces
            while index_tracker < length and string[index_tracker] not in spaces:
                index_tracker += 1

            words.append(string[beginning_of_word:index_tracker])

        index_tracker += 1

    return "".join(reverse_string_3(string))
```

Comment: You can still use slicing to reverse a string?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your current code merely defines a function and quits without getting called.  You haven't told us what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_string(s):
    if not s: # a base case ...
       return ""
    return s[-1] + reverse_string(s[:-1]) # a recursive case
```

although these make terrible example problems because anyone in the real world would just use `reverse` or `s[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You have infinite recursion because your function has no base case and no proper recursion case.  Your "recursion" consists of calling the same function with the same data.

A recursive routine has two main parts:

1. A base case, a conditional clause that returns a simple value and does *not* recur.

In your case, this might be

```
if len(string) <= 1:
    return string
```

2. A recursion case, where you call the routine again, *with a simpler version of the problem*.  You combine this with a small processing step.  Your processing step works on a `words` list, but ignores that entirely in the control flow.  You need to fix this.  I can't give a suggestion here, because you haven't described your algorithm.